# Does transferring my DNS provider from GoDaddy to AWS, where my website is hosted, affects performance of the website?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

Trying to understand how routing works for a website and this question came to my mind... My Domain name is registered with GoDaddy and my website is hosted with AWS.

Does it mean request for my website are first routed to GoDaddy and then transferred to AWS? In other words, would it be more efficient for me to have my domain name registered with AWS when my website is hosted with AWS?

Comment: No... It is same you want to register your domain with godaddy or AWS. If you register your domain with Godaddy, then you just need to point your domain to AWS name server, the DNS will resolve within 12-24 hours. The best thing is don't use same provider for hosting and domain registration. It will better for you to separate it.

Comment: Thanks Mark, why is it best to separate them? I get why there is no advantage of doing both with AWS, but why separating them is better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The request will not be routed to GoDaddy first. Only the DNS request to resolve your domain will go to GoDaddy. Once the DNS resolves it to an IP, the actual HTTP request is sent to that IP - which is your AWS instance.

Once the DNS is resolved it is usually cached (typically for 300sec) and the DNS request not sent repeatedly. So you are not gaining much by moving the domain to AWS.

Very high level flow:

1. Type the URL of your website in the browser
2. The browser tries to resolve the URL to an IP (Request sent to GoDaddy Name Servers since the domain is registered with GoDaddy)
3. Browser sends the HTTP request to the IP